# Filtering query results in file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a web site.
This is part of my current code:

```
$num_cat_rec = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tb_revisiones_tor GROUP BY tipo_tor")
              or die (mysqli_error($dbh));

//display the results
while ($row_tor = mysqli_fetch_array($num_cat_rec))
{
    $puntos_tor_conseguidos =0; 
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-4">
        <!-- small box -->
        <div class="small-box bg-purple">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php 
                $usuario_tor = $row_tor['evaluado'] ;
                $tipo_tor = $row_tor['tipo_tor'];
                $puntos_tor_conseguidos = $puntos_tor_conseguidos+get_puntos_tor_conseguidos($usuario_tor,$tipo_tor);
                ?>
                <h3><?php echo $puntos_tor_conseguidos?></h3>
                <H4><?php echo $row_tor['nombre']?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-ribbon-a"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="otros_rubros_reporte.php" class="small-box-footer">
                <?php echo $lang['MORE_INFO']?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- ./col -->
    <?php
}
```

And this is the current output:

[image]

That is the database structure and some of the data.

[image]

As you may see, I am showing the data group by the field **nombre**, as it is shown in the picture as blue rectangles.

What I need is to show as big number the sum of the field **puntos** for each **nombre** group, but only for certain users (field **evaluado**)

The condition for the selected users must be:

```
get_unit($row_tor['evaluado']= $_POST['un'];
```

get_unit(x) is a function inside the PHP file.

How can I do this?

Comment: If it's to use `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`, why don't you try with it and I believe, for certain users, you can filter out with a `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Modify your query to:

   ```
   SELECT SUM(puntos) as puntos_sum,* FROM tb_revisiones_tor GROUP BY tipo_tor
   ```

   to get the sum of **puntos** for every group of **nombre**
2. Add condition to display the sum:

   ```
   if ($row_tor['evaluado']==$_POST['un']){
      echo $row_tor['puntos_sum'];
   }
   ```

   Note: use **==** for comparing, not **=**